# Who is blowing the horn to alert the Night's Watch?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Whenever the white walkers come in [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/), they said that they blow horns.

They blow once for fellow rangers, twice for wildlings/foes and three times for "the others" but I don't get it, who exactly is blowing the horn?

Answer (score 8):

Whoever is 'on watch' in any situations knows the protocol for raising an alert - as you say 'once for Rangers returning, two for wildlings and three for the the others'.

At Castle Black this is presumably someone at the top of The Wall, but when they were encamped while riding north, they put someone on watch who uses the same signals.  Presumably that person/people go up a local hill (if available) to get a good view.

That said, I think any 'brother' would use the same signals if they encounter someone, not just those on watch.  So anyone else hearing a horn is automatically listening for the number to determine whether its a threat or not.

Comment: But this makes me think, Who in seven hells would want to not run but blow a freaking horn when they see the others coming. But i guess its the "Crows" thing. Thank you for your answer, it makes sense.

Comment: @user3523123 You blow the horn not just to warn people, but to get help too.  Better to warn your brothers of an attack and perhaps get help for yourself.

Comment: @user3523123 Who in the seven hell who want to forfeit any rights and titles (and sex) for his life to defend others on a freezing castle ? as stated in the book, some members of the watch are less dedicated and more me-first. But most of them are altruistic and dedicated to others.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: fellow crows (truly brothers :)).

Or are you asking about the particular situation in S02E10, where Samwell, Grenn and Ed hear the three horn blows at the Fist of the first men?

If yes, watch beginning of S03E01 for the answer :-). Samwell thinks it's Jon Snow and Qhorin Halfhand, but their rangers' group has been killed/captured. It's the group of crows lead by Lord Commander Jeor Mormont.